# Can I decide where the overflow menu goes?

Tags: android

[image]

You can see from above that the overflow menu is appearing to the right of the icons. Can I choose where this overflow item appears?

Here's my XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
    android:id="@+id/add_blind_schedule"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:orderInCategory="6"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/current_buddies"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cc_bcc"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/your_buddies"
    />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/restore"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/restore_default"
    />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/about"
    />

</menu>
```

Comment: No. you cant change position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant decide where it is display.its display place is fixed. if you want to display it to your own place then you have to create your own overflow menu with sub menu items and then set it to your own place.